# How to change date to hours

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel

Hello I'm trying to check how long message is in database I'm using laravel4 framework and I have this:

```
date( "h", strtotime($message->created_at)) - date('h')
```

but it only counts hours I need to change days and month to hours and then count how long is it in the database. How can i do it?

Comment: Do you want to count hours between two dates or do you want to get the hour of the current day (e.g. 12 o clock)?

Comment: You should count the difference in epoch seconds, then divide by 3600.

Comment: I want to count hours between two dates. And first date is getting by this way date( "h", strtotime($message->created_at))

Comment: @WesleyMurch it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

`date()` returns a string, and you can't do math on strings. `date('h')` returns the current hour, eg: `10` now because it is 10am. If `$message->created_at` was `Feb 3, 1978 10:01:02` then `date('h', strtotime($message->created_at))` would return `10` as well.

Assuming `$message->created_at` is in an [acceptable format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php):

```
$diff_in_hours = (time() - strtotime($message->created_at)) / 3600;
```

Comment: You beat me, I was about to post the same thing :) +1 to keep the old spirit of SO alive.

Comment: I recived something like this -108.999232

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but it sounds to me like you're looking for what is called a "human readable timestamp". If you've set up your database table correctly, both created_at and updated_at should be retrieved as [carbon objects](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), giving you several different ways to display your date. It's actually very simple to achieve the desired effect:

`$message->created_at->diffForHumans()`

This should then print a readable time just like you see here on stackoverflow (1 hour ago, 23 minutes ago, etc...).

Check out the link for more information about carbon objects.